# This loop outputs always the same number (iPad c compiler)

Tags: c, for-loop, output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    int n;

    for(int i = 1; i<30; i++) 
    {
        n = i*i+i+i+i+1;
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like this code to execcute a certain number for every value of `i`. However it always outputs `664`.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: I would rather say it outputs hello world followed by a number of new lines... Post the actual code.

Comment: Always output  664? I dont even see where you write the output

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: see this https://ideone.com/wwNSZ1

Answer (score 4):

I think you forgot to print `n`, if I understood you correctly.

The command `printf("\n");` should only print a new line.

Try instead: `printf("%d\n",n);`.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
   printf("%d\n",n);
```

With your code i got compilation error "error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode"

Did you compile by turning on C99 mode?

By using

```
    -std=c99
```

after successful compilation(Note: Add the above printf line) got the different values on execution.